# If headers of an interface change, why clients of the interface need to be recompiled?

Tags: c++

As I read the problem statement of **item31**: **Minimize compilation dependencies between files** of *Effective C++*, the following statement puzzles me:

```
class Person {

  public:

     Person(const std::string& name, const Date& birthday,

            const Address& addr);

     std::string name() const;

     std::string birthDate() const;

     std::string address() const;

     ...

  private:

      std::string theName;        // implementation detail

      Date theBirthDate;          // implementation detail

      Address theAddress;         // implementation detail

};
```

> in the file defining the **Person** class, you are likely to find something like this:
>
> #include < string>
>
> #include "date.h"
>
> #include "address.h"
>
> Unfortunately, this sets up a compilation dependency between the file defining Person and these header files. If any of these header files (comment mine: the headers listed above, namely < string>, "date.h", "address.h") is changed, or if any of the header files they depend on changes, the file containing the Person class must be recompiled, as must **any files that use Person**.

What I don't quite understand is the last part highlighted. Why do clients that use Person need recompilation? They just need to **relink** to the newly compiled Person object code, right (I am assuming the **Person** interface remains the same to its clients)?

If what clients really need - assuming the Person interface doesn't change - is just a relinking, does it still warrant the Pimpl idiom? The Pimpl class still need recompilation if any of the headers changes. The idiom only saves the client one relinking.

**EDIT**: It seems that there is a lot of confusion about what headers have changed. In this case, Scott Meyers was talking about the header files included by **Person.h** are changed. But **Person.h** itself does not change so clients using (#including) Person.h doesn't see a change (no timestamp change on Person.h). The makefile dependency would list Person.o as a prerequisite so the client will simply link with the new Person.o. I am learning Pimpl idiom, maybe I missed some obvious points in everyone's argument. Please elucidate.

**EDIT2**: When client needs to use Person, it includes Person.h which also include all the other included file such as date.h and address.h. I missed this part and thought only Person.cpp need to deal with these headers.

Comment: You keep repeating "the headers change". I've asked you several times to define _how_ they change, in your chosen scenario, but you've yet to provide that crucial detail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is an intermediate step in compiling. i.e. if you compile foo.cpp and it includes a.h ab b.h then an intermediate source file

```
 a.h content
 b.h content
 foo.cpp content
```

which is the input for compilation is created. note that if other headers are included in headers, they are also listed recursively.
since a chance in header cause your 
compilation file, the intermediate file, change, foo.cpp should be recompiled.

Comment: I am assuming separate compilation is in place. clients of a class only need to link to the class object code if the class interface is not changed.

Comment: @Rich possibly you did not encapsulate your interface class well. this is another topic. but your  situation is clear. if an included header chances you shoul recompile.

Comment: Person.h may include some files that changed. But Person.h did NOT change. That is what I meant. Clients including "Person.h" only need to re-link instead of compilation.

Comment: @Rich i suggest you to read my answer with attention. you are criticising gravity while you have to live on earth

Comment: I understand that you are saying how include works. But clients may just have a compiled object code. All it has to do is re-link with the new object file of Person without going through a full compilation. Unless I totally missed your point?

Comment: @Rich my point is: the file is changed and it should be recompiled. you think that the functions are called from that source file did not change so no need to recompile but i.e. what about the data types gotten from that file?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89494/discussion-between-ataman-and-rich).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but that re-linkage will fail if the datatype sizes are wrong, or the old code is trying to link to code that no longer exists. It's not magic: the code, at link-time, has still been compiled.

There is a subset of interface changes you can make without breaking binary compatibility; adding members to a type is not part of that subset.

> (I am assuming the Person interface remains the same to its clients)

This is the key. Your assumption has removed the constraints, so the answer to "why do the other files need to be recompiled" becomes "they don't".

Obviously, the quote in its original context does not mention that assumption, which is why it is giving broader guidelines. Though, personally, I'd have liked to have seen a more in-depth explanation from Meyers of binary compatibility.

Comment: I am assuming the Person class interface remains the same. No addition/deletion/edit of members.

Comment: @Rich: Then you need to tell us what you mean by "the header file is changed". Details matter.

Comment: To be specific : the header files Scott Meyers refers to are <string>, "date.h" and "address.h"

Comment: Person is implemented using string, date, and address. That is Person's job to interact with them. Person's clients should not worry about them, I suppose.

Comment: @Rich: Not sure why you're not answering my question. Oh well. Can't help further then.

Comment: Nope; we have reached the extent of support I'm willing to provide for free. :) I don't do one-on-one mentoring.

Comment: Simple example: the definition of `Date` changed, they added one field. Now the size of `Person` changed, so whichever function allocated a `Person` on the stack has to change the whole stack layout.

Comment: @MatteoItalia OH! When clients include Person.h, it automatically include all the other header files included by Person.h ... I totally missed this part... so stupid I am. I thought only Person.cpp should deal with the members of class Person instead of its clients.

Answer (score 0):

In a very practical sense: Suppose that `person.h` includes other files, or defines some preprocessor symbols. If you change its includes or change its preprocessors symbol, then any file that also includes `person.h` potentially has its meaning changed.

In practice the compiler will fully recompile any compilation units affected by the change, if I understand correctly. And even if there are some optimizations to avoid doing lots of work when only "minor" or "insignficant" changes take place, like adding whitespace or something, the compiler needs to at least look at any compilation unit whose text was potentially changed in order to be sure.

Generally speaking, most tool-chains don't cache the intermediate results of each compilation unit after preprocessor expansion, and even if you are using something like ccache it's not going to try to do anything intelligent with the cached stuff to avoid doing work when only small changes happen, it's only going to try to check if it's stale or not.

So, changing things in a header file that may seem even smaller than changing the layout or interface of a class, still needs to trigger recompilation generally. What if some of the compilation units contain queries like `sizeof` your class? Or use SFINAE tricks to detect if it has certain methods?

Answer (score 0):

The core information in a header file describes interfaces.

An interface to a function describes its arguments (how many, what type, etc) and return type.    The actual function implementation (definition) requires the function be called in an expected way - and the interface describes that.   If code that is calling the function provides a different set of arguments, or if it acts as if the function returns something different than it actually does,  then there will be a malfunction somewhere (either in the function, since it is not given information it expects, or in the caller, since the function doesn't give information the caller expects).

This means, if the interface to a function changes, then both code for the called function and for the callers need to be recompiled, in order to ensure consistency.

The same goes for type definitions.   `struct` and `class` types may include member functions, and the compiler needs to ensure consistency between behaviour of those functions and their callers (or the programmer has to deal with inconsistency, which may manifest in tricky ways).   Also, when creating an instance of a type (i.e. an object or a variable) the compiler needs to know the size of the type (how much memory it needs, how far the second element of an array is from the first, etc) in order to work with objects correctly.

All of this information is specified in the interface, which is typically placed in headers.    Yes, the compiler might get away with making assumptions if it is not given information (e.g. in C, a function is assumed to return `int` and accept an arbitrary set of arguments if it is called without being previously declared) but there is still the problem of mismatches (e.g. if the function is assumed to return `int`, but actually returns a pointer of some type, what happens?).

More prosaically, build management processes (makefiles, build scripts, etc) typically check creation dates of files.  For example, a source file may be recompiled if the corresponding object is older than that source file, or older than any of the header files that source file `#include`s.   The logic of doing that is that the content of source file and its included headers affect how code in the compiled object behaves and, if the object file is older than one of those files, then there may well have been a change.   The only way to make things line up is to recompile.

It would be possible to only recompile if a "substantive" change of file content has occurred (e.g. not recompile if only a comment has been changed in a header).  However, doing that would mean it is necessary to reliably detect that the change in a file actually doesn't matter to the working of the program.   The analysis to do that is certainly possible, but will often be more complicated - and time consuming, which is a problem as programmers tend to whine about long build times - than simply checking file dates.